# How to round 21.87499999999994 to 21.88?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, js, rounding

I know this is very specific but is just an example, I already tried:

```
Math.round(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2").toFixed(2, 3, 4..)
```

`Math.trunc` `Math.pow`.. But nothing works.. How to acchive this? `21.87499999999994 => 21.88`

Comment: this question belongs on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can use toFixed to effect this type of rounding. It does require two passes though, first to round up, and again to get the correct precision. First, we'll define a function that converts a float to a specific precision, and back to a float.

```
function round(value, precision) {
  return parseFloat(value.toFixed(precision));
}
```

To get the value that you'd like, first round one more precision than what you need, then to the precision you need. That looks like this:

```
let output = round(round(input, 3), 2);
```

Or as a function itself:

```
function roundUp(value, precision) {
  return round(round(value, precision + 1), precision);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 solution for the same

**Solution 1:**

```
let num = 21.87499999999994;
let roundedVal = num.toFixed(3); //21.875
roundedVal = Math.round(roundedVal*100)/100; //21.88
console.log('Final Rounded Value is ' + roundedVal);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
Math.round(Math.round(num*1000)/10)/100
```

Here First we multiply this number by 1000 so we get new number for round off. 21875

```
21.87499999999994*1000 = 21874.99999999994
Math.round(21.87499999999994*1000) = 21875
```

So now we have output is 21875. Now we will divide this by 10 and round of again.

```
21875/10 = 2187.5
Math.round(2187.5) = 2188
```

to get final output we will divide this by 100 and output will be available.

Here this will solve for 3 decimal places only.

If you requires some dynamic calculation then please add more details like till which number we need to check.

Ref : https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-round-to-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places-in-javascript-ed74c471c1b8

Answer (score 0):

To round 21.87499999999994 to 21.88 in javascript, you can use the `toFixed` method of the `Number` object. This method takes a number as its argument and returns a string representation of the number with the specified number of decimal places. For example, you can use the following code:

```
let num = 21.87499999999994;
let rounded = num.toFixed(2);
console.log('rounded is ' + rounded);
```

This code will round the number num to two decimal places and assign the result to the variable rounded. The result will be a string with the value `"21.87"`. If the number after `.87` is greater than `5` then it will return the `21.88`. Currently, after the `.87` is 4 that is why it will return the result as `21.87`.

Ref:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Not Apex, JavaScript.

Comment: Updated the answer as per the Comment.